# Error while allocating space to the database

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a database script and having an error while executing it. I am trying to create a database and assign space. Where am I going wrong

Here is the error message

MODIFY FILE encountered operating system error 112(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to expand the physical file 'E:\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\CoreReferenceStaging.mdf'.

```
USE master
GO

CREATE DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [CoreReferenceStaging] 
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'CoreReferenceStaging', SIZE = 51200000KB , FILEGROWTH = 2560000KB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE [CoreReferenceStaging] 
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'CoreReferenceStaging_log', SIZE = 15360000KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024000KB )
GO
```

Comment: When I type `NET HELPMSG 112` from a command prompt, the resultant message is "There is not enough space on the disk".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entering `NET HELPMSG 112` from a command prompt, the resultant message is "There is not enough space on the disk". It seems there isn't enough space on the E drive volume to extend the file to the specified size.

Answer (score 0):

Your FILEGROWTH is way too big (2.5GB). It probably can't grow by that much. Change it to 100MB (100000KB). Same for your log.